# why i see two kind of IP at my ping?

Tags: firewall, ip, dns-hosting

i have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with external DNS Server on it.

all domains works fine but when i ping one of theme i get this result and site is down .

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ping xxx.com

Pinging xxx.com [162.217.xxx.xxx] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 38.104.xxx.xxx: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 38.104.xxx.xxx: TTL expired in transit.
Reply from 38.104.xxx.xxx: TTL expired in transit.

Ping statistics for 162.217.xxx.xxx:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 3, Lost = 1 (25% loss),
```

but when i ping my server's IP directly it works fine and normal.

is it a problem with my firewall or DNS?

Comment: Nothing about this question makes sense to me. `i have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with external DNS Server on it.` - What does that mean? Are you hosting a DNS zone for a public domain on this server? `all domains works fine but when i ping one of theme i get this result and site is down` - You're pinging a domain? Do you mean that you're pinging the FQDN of the domains being hosted on this DNS server? Where does the A record for the naked domain point to? A valid host that should respond to ping? Where are you pinging from? `TTL expired in transit` is usually indicative of a routing loop.

Comment: @joe... i did not remember to ask you or want you to answer me DEAR,if this question does not make sens... do not answer it like this,learn to respect to others

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying. I simply said that the question didn't make sense to me and asked some follow up questions to get more detail. If you don't like that then don't post your questions here and don't bring your attitude to someone who is asking you follow up questions. Learn to ask better questions with more detail. There is nothing about my comment or questions that was disrespectful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The First IP is the IP that has been resolved by the DNS-Server.

The second IP should be your Router that tells you that the **TTL expired in transit**. So when the destination is not reachable. The last router gives you an error.

Comment: Thanks for help, but how can i handle it and why another sub domain and domain are working?